# Find a value within a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing an exercise on JavaScript. But I get an error. Cant find what is wrong. The script should check the array if the "name" exist.

```js
// Array with names

var names = ["Alex", "Mike", "John"];


// Function checks if name exist

name.checkName = function(name) {
  return (this[name] >= 0) ?
    alert(name + " is there!") :
    alert(name + " is not there!")
};


//Function call

name.checkName('Alex');
```

Comment: Your array is `names`, but you're assigning to `name.checkName`. That looks wrong.

Comment: you need to say `indexOf`.

Comment: There's also the `name` vs `names` issue.

Comment: In addition to the typographical error, there is the logic error (`indexOf` vs. square brackets). IMO this shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define "name", only "names". Additionally, use the indexOf() method. Try this (untested):

```
// Array with names

var names = ["Alex", "Mike", "John"];


// Function checks if name exist

names.checkName = function(name) {
   return (this.indexOf(name) >= 0) ?
   alert(name + " is there!") :
   alert(name + " is not there!")
};


//Function call

names.checkName('Alex');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i am not profficient with js but i know python and it is the same idea

```
var names = ["Alex", "Mike", "John"];

    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        if (names[i] = name){
           alert(name + " is there")
        }else{
           alert(name + " is not there")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to check if `name` is in the `names` array.
You'll also need to declare checkName.

```
var names = ["Alex", "Mike", "John"];

var checkName = function(name) {
  return (names.indexOf(name) > -1) ?
    alert(name + " is there!") :
    alert(name + " is not there!")
};

checkName('Alex');
```